# Could not open client transport for any of the Server URI's in ZooKeeper: GSS initiate failed -- no issues with beeline or hive2

Tags: hadoop, jdbc, hive, apache-zookeeper, dbeaver

I am having issues with connecting Dbeaver using zookeeper. I am getting error "Could not open client transport for any of the Server URI's in ZooKeeper: GSS initiate failed". Initially I assumed it was to do with kerberos. However, I am able to connect dbeaver to Hive2 using same kerberos ticket

Works properly. in dbeaver

jdbc:hive2://server1:10000/tsz;AuthMech=1;KrbRealm=REALM.COM;KrbHostFQDN=server1; KrbServiceName=hive;KrbAuthType=2;AuthMech=1

Fails in Dbeaver
jdbc:hive2://server1:2181,server2:2181,server3:2181/;serviceDiscoveryMode=zooKeeper;transportMode=binary;zooKeeperNamespace=hiveserver2;KrbRealm=REALM.COM;KrbHostFQDN=server1; KrbServiceName=hive;KrbAuthType=2;AuthMech=1

Connection string works in beeline with zookeeper. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: I have the same issue. putty connects fine, however, dbvisualizer cant.